# want to open a form to save the comments on click of data point in highstock chart

Tags: highcharts

Actually i am using the Highstock library and I am generating a graph with line chart (Data Grouping) with using PHP and MySQL. I am using a JSON format to plot the chart.

I am able to plot the graph with my database. Now I want to open a popup form on click of any data point with ID (primary key in database) of that record and want to save the comment in database.

Data structure my table have **ID** as primary key, **Time** (x Value), **Points** (Y value), **Comments** (Wants to enter from chart form)

1. ID: 1,2,3,4,5,6
2. Time: 1345575960000, 1345576140000, 1345663860000, 1345690200000, 1345719780000, 1345741920000
3. Points: 1720, 2040, 2570, 1477, 978, 3007
4. Comments: (This i want to update from chart form)

In this Structure ID is primary key. So i want to save the comments on the basis of ID.
I want to save the comments when i click on data point in cha.

Can you please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? The clicking on a point in highcharts or the getting of data once clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trap the clicking of points using

```
series.dataevents.click
```

Eg. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click/

Once trapped, you could display a dialog with your form on it? The form can submit back to your server to save the comments and then hide itself.

Create your points follows:

```
{
  x: 1142812800000,
  Y: 55,
  id: 12345
}
```

Comment: By using this i will open popup with form but how i can pass the ID to save the records.

Comment: The example given by you is passing the this.category and this.y, which is value of x axis and y axis. How can i pass id.

Comment: You can add a ID attribute to the point, alongside x and y. You can then reference this.id

Comment: I am using this method: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

In this chart it is using JSON format like this
http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

Which has only X and Y value i tried to enter third column with ID but not able to retrieve ID on chart

Comment: I have created my points like this [{"x":1345575960000,"y":"1281.41","id":"1"},{"x":1345575960000,"y":"1271.3","id":"2"},{"x":1345575960000,"y":"1296.58","id":"3"},{"x":1345575960000,"y":"1316.81","id":"4"},{"x":1345575960000,"y":"1261.18","id":"5"},{"x":1345575960000,"y":"1316.81","id":"6"},{"x":1345575960000,"y":"1306.7","id":"7"},{"x":1345576020000,"y":"0","id":"8"},{"x":1345576020000,"y":"0","id":"9"},{"x":1345576020000,"y":"0","id":"10"}]

but it is not generating the chart.

Comment: Y should be a number not a quoted string

Comment: I am creating this JSON dynamically and i am not adding these quote.

Comment: What did your data look like before?

Comment: IT was look like this  [{1345575960000, 1281.41, 1},
 {1345575960000, 1271.3, 2},
 {1345575960000, 1296.58, 3},
 {1345575960000, 1316.81, 4},
 {1345575960000, 1261.18, 5},
 {1345575960000, 131‌​6.81, 6},
 {1345575960000, 1306.7, 7},
 {1345576020000, 0, 8},
 {1345576020000, 0, 9},
 {1345576020000, 0, 10}]

Comment: No quotes around the y values there.